# Converting a date, time and offset into an ISO8601 DateTime using moment.js and moment timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I am processing some itinerary data where the times and dates are all provided in the **local** timezone.  I am adding this data to a database where I'd like to store all of the dates in UTC, with the proper timezone offset.  I'm trying to process these dates with moment.js.

The input string for date/time is formatted like this `2020-07-12 13:00` and the timezone is in this format `Europe/Amsterdam`.

I want to end up with a string like:

`2020-07-12T11:00:00+02:00`

The trouble I'm having, is that moment converts my input time to either local time or utc if I use the `.utc()` method.

This code is getting me the correct result, but I don't understand why and I'm not sure if I can rely on its accuracy:

```
var offset = moment.tz(`Europe/Amsterdam`).utcOffset();
var m = moment(`2020-07-12 13:00`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').utc().subtract(240 + offset + offset, 'minutes').utcOffset(offset); // (240 is my own UTC offset)
```

How can I simply input a date, time and timezone and end up with a correct ISO8601 DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Moment and Moment-TimeZone in your app, then you can simply do the following:

```
const m = moment.tz('2020-07-12 13:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm', 'Europe/Amsterdam');
m.format() //=> "2020-07-12T13:00:00+02:00"
```

However, the Moment team recommends using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) for new development.  The equivalent is:

```
const dt = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat('2020-07-12 13:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', { zone: 'Europe/Amsterdam'});
dt.toISO()  //=> "2020-07-12T13:00:00.000+02:00"
```

The only difference being that milliseconds are included.  You can use a different formatting function if you prefer a different output.

The main benefit of Luxon is that it uses the built-in time zone functionality provided by the ECMAScript Internationalization API, whereas Moment-Timezone bundles its own time zone data - which can be quite large.

Also, note that in your question by asking for `2020-07-12T11:00:00+02:00` you seem to be misunderstanding the ISO 8601 format.  In that format, the time presented *is* the local time.  Thus, it should be `13:00`, not `11:00`.   The `+02:00` means, "this was the offset from UTC *for this local time*".  (It doesn't mean that you apply the offset to get the local time.)

Comment: Thank you for your last paragraph!  I'll test this and accept your answer.  Perhaps this is why I was having to do so much subtraction.